# I am having trouble using arthimetic operators in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an assignment and have to take a 10 word string and decide what category it would fall under. The string can be anything and it has to be defined by 3 categories:
1. Cat. A - Body of string where more than half of the words are 4 characters or less
2. Cat. B - Body of string is neither Cat. A or Cat. C
3. Cat. C - Body of string where more than half of the words are 7 characters or more

The issue I am having is not knowing what variables and operators to use to begin dissecting the original string . If someone could give be a list of steps that I should do I would be able to complete it.

Here is my work so far:

```
var sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs tomorrow";

var sentenceSplit = sentence.split(" ");


sentenceSplit[0];
sentenceSplit[1];
sentenceSplit[2];
sentenceSplit[3];
sentenceSplit[4];
sentenceSplit[5];
sentenceSplit[6];
sentenceSplit[7];
sentenceSplit[8];
sentenceSplit[9];

if (sentenceSplit[0].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[1].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[2].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[3].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[4].length <= 4 
   || sentenceSplit[5].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[6].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[7].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[8].length <= 4 || sentenceSplit[9].length <= 4) {
    print ("good"); 
}else{
    print ("bad"); 
}
```

Comment: Have two counters, one for words >= 4 characters and one for words >= 7 characters. Iterate over the array of words, get the length of each word and increase the corresponding counter. E.g. `if (word.length <= 4) { words4 += 1; }`. Afterwards compare the counters with the length of the array (e.g. `if (words4 > words.length / 2)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of problems it's better to use for loops instead of untidy if statement,it's easy to implement as follows:

```js
      let catAindicator = 0;
      let catBindicator = 0;
      let catCindicator = 0;

     for (let item of sentenceSplit) {

            if (item.length <= 4) {
                console.log(item + " is Cat A");
                catAindicator++;
            } else if (item.length >= 7) {
                console.log(item + " is Cat C");
                catCindicator++;
            } else {
                console.log(item + " is Cat B");
                catBindicator++;
            }

        }

        console.log(catAindicator); //count of cat A words
        console.log(catCindicator); //count of cat C words
        console.log(catBindicator); //count of cat B words
```

Now you can simply evaluate the string Category by the category majority of its sub-strings by using the three variables that indicate the count of category string e.g. `catAindicator` which increases within first condition as `catAindicator++` and so on, then compare them and you get the result. It would be something like:

```js
      if (catAindicator > catBindicator && catAindicator > catCindicator){
            console.log("String is Cat A");
      } else if (catCindicator > catAindicator && catCindicator > catBindicator){
            console.log("String is Cat C");
      } else {
            console.log("String is Cat B");
      }
```

Comment: Well after trying what you suggested the code will put every word into a category not the entire string.

Comment: Hello, i edited the answer to show how you can use this to evaluate the category of entire ```sentenceSplit``` string

Comment: After further editing my code as well I decided to test this string: Ability absence academy account yes yes yes yes yes yes. The output is saying that this is a cat. c string while it should be cat. a.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and got that issue, I don't know if I have to change anything from the first part of your code and just paste the bottom half.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your feedback i found that there is no need for the inner ```for``` loop for your problem just remove it, i will edit mybanswer so you can see it.

Comment: Yes this works! All I had to do was remove the ```console.log``` functions inside the ```for```loop and the three ```console.log``` functions at the bottom of the ```for``` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could something like try ...

In the case below. The average variable provides you with the average word length.

```
var resultEl = document.getElementById("results"),
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs tomorrow",
lengths = []

var sentenceSplit = sentence.split(" ");

sentenceSplit.forEach(addToTotal);
function addToTotal(element)
{
    lengths.push(element.length);
}

var aboveFour = lengths.filter(word => word > 4),
aboveSeven = lengths.filter(word => word > 7),
category = "";

if (Math.floor(aboveFour.length) >= Math.floor(sentenceSplit.length / 2)) {
    category = "A";
}
else if (Math.floor(aboveSeven.length) >= Math.floor(sentenceSplit.length / 2)) {
    category = "C";
}
else {
    category = "B";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work because even though half of the words are 7 characters  it says that the string would fall under cat. b. I believe that has to do with the code finding the average word length and not the length of each specific word.